# Debugging React Native over adb tcpip

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, usb-otg

I'm trying to attach a USB device (using USB OTG) to my Android device while developing an app using React-Native. Classically to debug an Android app, one connects using USB debug mode over adb, but since my USB port is being used for my USB OTG device, that's not possible.

I tried to use the `adb tcpip` method ([How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)) but that doesn't work because my device can't find the 'development server'. Has anyone had any luck debugging this way?

Comment: is the USB you using came with the mobile or you purchased it from a different vendor ?

Comment: (note sure that's relevant, but i'll answer anyways) I can debug over USB just fine with all the cables I use. The problem is when I need to use the phone's USB port to test another USB peripheral (e.g., keyboard or mouse). Debugging requires the phone to be in USB guest most, while when connecting a peripheral it needs to be in USB host mode (see USB OTG), which prevents me from using a USB hub to get more ports. If I can debug react native over TCPIP that would free up my USB port.

Comment: ok, sorry I dont have much knowledge of USB OTG but I myself debug my RN app over wifi n/w (though initially I had to install apk to the mobile which you can easily do it manually ) . Then you can set your ip address in dev settings . Also I want to know which OS are you using?

Comment: no worries. The TL;DR of USB OTG is that your phone can be a USB host and you need a special $2 adapter. Now you know as much as me ;-)

Comment: Interesting. So you basically followed the these directions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) and it worked for RN? Or did you do someting special? What version of RN? I'm on Mac OS El Cap. React Native 0.45.

Comment: I forgot to tell one thing: I was not running the app using `react-native run-android` command (though initially I did that for building apk) .I am using `npm start` .RN v0.46.1 and I am on windows

Comment: Not sure how react native works, but if you install the apps over usb debugging, `adb tcpip` followed by `adb connect` to your phone's IP would make the phone work just like if it was connected (with respect to usb debugging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your phone and the PC used for development are connected in the same LAN. From the **Rage Shake menu** (shake the device while your app's screen is active) you should be able to navigate to `Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device` which lets you enter the IP & port of the development server for loading from the packager.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!